# UX resources for very specific use cases (Surveillance software)

Tags: usability

I'll try my question as specific as possible. Where can I find UX or usability research regarding special use cases, such as video management software for surveillance systems?

Almost all of the research I've found focuses on websites or mobile applications, and my concern is that it may not always be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small sector so the amount of research on it will be smaller: I'd try looking a bit broader - ie for video management software (which should cover video editing software).

You might also want to look at 'control room' software as this will find similar applications

It's a small but high value sector as control rooms tend to be bespoke, eg:

http://www.siemens.com/innovation/en/publikationen/publications_pof/pof_spring_2008/tailored_solutions/usability.htm

*Usability experts at Siemens Power Distribution therefore rely on analyses of work procedures as well as on-site evaluations and user tests; these are studied in the lab of the Georg-Simon-Ohm College in Nuremberg, for example. The lab investigates reciprocal connections between man and machine, sometimes using sophisticated techniques like eye-tracking. In this process, a camera films the face of the user at a simulated operator console in a control room. Software using image recognition calculates which monitor messages the operator is looking at when he or she deals with certain tasks. "One thing we can see from this is whether we’re giving the user maximum support with his work," says Höfler.*

Similar methods to websites and apps - but just a more specialised application.

Historically this kind of thing used to be called 'Human Factors', though nowadays with increasing use of software interfaces its really just another part of UX.